# How to I change this code from UI Route to the core ng-Route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I bought a template from wrapbootrap, however the code provided there used the UI Route plugin. The ui route is excellent because you can have states, views, nested views.  However it doesnt work with the ADAL Authentication library for Azure authentication.

The following code was the one provided by the theme:

Config.js

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider, $httpProvider) {

    // Configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
    IdleProvider.timeout(120); // in seconds

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard_1");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
        debug: false
    });

    $stateProvider

        .state('dashboards', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboards",
            templateUrl: "views/common/content.html",

        })
        .state('dashboards.dashboard_1', {
            url: "/dashboard_1",
            templateUrl: "views/dashboard_1.html",
            requireADLogin: true,
            resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        {

                            serie: true,
                            name: 'angular-flot',
                            files: ['js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angles',
                            files: ['js/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angular-peity',
                            files: ['js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'js/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
        })
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="inspinia">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Page title set in pageTitle directive -->
    <title page-title></title>

    <!-- Font awesome -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Main Inspinia CSS files -->
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="loadBefore" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<!-- ControllerAs syntax -->
<!-- Main controller with serveral data used in Inspinia theme on diferent view -->
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

<!-- Main view  -->
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- jQuery and Bootstrap -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- MetsiMenu -->
<script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>

<!-- SlimScroll -->
<script src="js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<!-- Peace JS -->
<script src="js/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom and plugin javascript -->
<script src="js/inspinia.js"></script>

<!-- Main Angular scripts-->
<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/angular-idle/angular-idle.js"></script>

<!--
 You need to include this script on any page that has a Google Map.
 When using Google Maps on your own site you MUST signup for your own API key at:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key
 After your sign up replace the key in the URL below..
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDQTpXj82d8UpCi97wzo_nKXL7nYrd4G70"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/adal/adal.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/adal/adal-angular.js"></script>

<!-- Anglar App Script -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/config.js"></script>
<script src="js/translations.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and content.html

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div ng-include="'views/common/navigation.html'"></div>

    <!-- Page wraper -->
    <!-- ng-class with current state name give you the ability to extended customization your view -->
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg {{$state.current.name}}">

        <!-- Page wrapper -->
        <div ng-include="'views/common/topnavbar.html'"></div>

        <!-- Main view  -->
        <div ui-view></div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div ng-include="'views/common/footer.html'"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- End page wrapper-->

    <!-- Right Sidebar -->
    <div ng-include="'views/common/right_sidebar.html'"></div>

</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->
```

However as the UI route doesnt work well with ADAL, I changed config.JS and now my authentication with azure works perfect.

```
function config($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider){

    $routeProvider.when("/dashboard_1", {
        controller: "MainCtrl",
        templateUrl: "/views/dashboard_1.html",
        requireADLogin: true,
        resolve: {
                        loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                {

                                    serie: true,
                                    name: 'angular-flot',
                                    files: [ 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'js/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'js/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'angles',
                                    files: ['js/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'js/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'angular-peity',
                                    files: ['js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'js/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
                                }
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/dashboard_1" });

    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
       {
           instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
           tenant: 'mysaasapp.onmicrosoft.com',
           clientId: '33e037a7-b1aa-42ab-9693-6c22d01ca338',
           extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1'
           //cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
       },
       $httpProvider
       );    
}
angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .config(config)
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
```

The problem is that I dont know how to use nested views or layouts pages with the core NG Route, how should I rewrite my index.html/content.html to accomodate this change.

This results in that I get my content rendered but not my left navigation bar or top bar.

Comment: ngRoute don't have nested views, or ngNewRouter 1.4+ has it. change ui-view to ng-view on index.html and move all of content.html inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.html change `uiview` by `ng-view`. Since `ng-route` does not allow nested views you should include the route to your `content.html` in the route provider as another state.